# Use User assigned identity to AKS cluster using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I want to deploy AKS cluster with User Assigned Identity. I have created the User assigned managed Identity before the cluster creation and pass this as a parameter. However, When I use the same in the ARM template, below is the observation:

1. If the 'Identity" is 'SystemAssigned' -> The deployment will be successful
2. If the 'Identity is 'UserAssigned' and provide the Resource ID for UserAssignedIdentity, the deployment fails telling that the 'servicePrincipalProfile' is not provided.
3. If the 'Identity is 'UserAssigned' and 'servicePrincipalProfile' is provided ->Deployment is successful, but when I query the cluster for its Identity, the UserAssignedIdentity details are blank.

ARM Template reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters#ManagedClusterServicePrincipalProfile

Template part that i am updating:

```
"identity": {
        "principalId": null,
        "tenantId": null,
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[parameters('userAssignedIdentitiesResourceID')]": {
            "clientId": "[parameters('userAssignedIdentitiesClientID')]",
            "principalId": "[parameters('userAssignedIdentitiesPrincipalID')]"
          }
        }
      }
```

Update:
I tried setting the User MSI via REST API after creating the AKS cluster (with SystemAssignedIdentity), but, it is not getting updated. I can still see the cluster identity as 'SystemAssignedIdentity'.

(Note, 'Invoke-CoeRestMethod' is a custom wrapper function that calls the Invoke-RestMethod. Wrapper func used to cache the bearer token etc.,)

```
$Body = @"
                {"location": "west europe",
                    "identity": {
        "principalId": null,
        "tenantId": null,
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "/subscriptions/7e7f55d3-f30a-4bfd-a6be-1c59594b8592/resourcegroups/ITQIG-eu-rsv-manjug-dev/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/manjugtestmsi": {}
        }
      }
                      
                           }
"@

$Uri = ("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/7e7f55d3-f30a-4bfd-a6be-1c59594b8592/resourceGroups/ITQIG-eu-rsv-manjug-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/ITQIG-eu-manjug-aks-dev?api-version=2020-09-01")
Invoke-CoeRestMethod -Method Put -Uri $Uri -Body $Body
```

Template used for AKS deployment:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
  "variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "create-mi-dict",
        "count": 1,
        "input": {
          "[resourceId('7e7f55d3-f30a-4bf-a6be-1c594b8592', 'ITQIG-eu-rsv-manjug-dev','Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'manjugtestmsi')]": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "parameters": {
    "clusterName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "aks101cluster",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Managed Cluster resource."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The location of the Managed Cluster resource."
      }
    },
    "userAssignedIdentitiesResourceID": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource ID of the User Assigned Identity."
      }
    },
    "userAssignedIdentitiesClientID": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client ID of the User Assigned Identity."
      }
    },
    "userAssignedIdentitiesPrincipalID": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Principal ID of the User Assigned Identity."
      }
    },
    "dnsPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "aks-coe-eu-manjug-dev-dns",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Optional DNS prefix to use with hosted Kubernetes API server FQDN."
      }
    },
    "osDiskSizeGB": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 0,
      "minValue": 0,
      "maxValue": 1023,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 will apply the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
      }
    },
    "agentCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "maxValue": 50,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The number of nodes for the cluster."
      }
    },
    "agentVMSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_DS2_v2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "linuxAdminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "User name for the Linux Virtual Machines."
      }
    },
    "sshRSAPublicKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Configure all linux machines with the SSH RSA public key string. Your key should include three parts, for example 'ssh-rsa AAAAB...snip...UcyupgH azureuser@linuxvm'"
      }
    },
    "osType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Linux",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Linux"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The type of operating system."
      }
    }
  },

  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
      "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('dnsPrefix')]",
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "maxPods": 110,
            "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSizeGB')]",
            "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
            "mode": "System",
            "count": "[parameters('agentCount')]",
            "vmSize": "[parameters('agentVMSize')]",
            "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
            "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
            "availabilityZones": [
              "1",
              "2",
              "3"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkPlugin": "kubenet",
          "loadBalancerSku": "Standard"
        },
        "addonProfiles": {
          "KubeDashboard": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "azurepolicy": {
            "enabled": true,
            "config": {
              "version": "v2"
            }
          },
          "httpApplicationRouting": {
            "enabled": true
          }
        },
        "linuxProfile": {
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('linuxAdminUsername')]",
          "ssh": {
            "publicKeys": [
              {
                "keyData": "[parameters('sshRSAPublicKey')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "enableRBAC": true,
        "aadProfile": {
          "managed": true,
          "enableAzureRBAC": true,
          "adminGroupObjectIDs": [
            "1f2a3b42-d409-4e5a-a530-cb899f033293"
          ]
        },
        "apiServerAccessProfile": {
          "enablePrivateCluster": false
        }
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": "[first(variables('create-mi-dict'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try to change`"principalId"` to `"objectId"`?

Comment: I tried by entirely skipping the 'clientid' and 'principalid', but still not works. Tried skipping because MS docs specifies just to provide the User MSI Resource ID. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters#managedclusteridentity-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

as of 12th July 2021 this is possible to do "normally":

```
"identity": {
    "type": "UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'xxx'))]": {}
    }
}
}
```

as far as I can tell that is correct (almost), but you cannot use parameters for property names in arm templates, so you'd have to pre-render the template.

```
"identity": {
    "type": "UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {
        "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/zzz": {}
    }
}
```

now that i think about it, you might get away with a copy function hack. I dont think there's any other way around it.

Example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "create-mi-dict",
                "count": 1,
                "input": {
                    "[resourceId('58aac3e3-e3c7-41e4-8539-5fd1893c46e9', 'rg-name','Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'mi-name')]": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "output1": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[first(variables('create-mi-dict'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: you can use it like so:

```
"identity": {
    "type": "UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": "[first(variables('create-mi-dict'))]"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do i use this Copy (variable) inside my ARM template.. do you have any references so i can understand? From your current example, you are referencing the variable in the Output.

Comment: check the update. so just assign the same thing as I assign in the output to the property

Comment: I used your hack, but i am getting a message 'variable create-mi-dict is undefined'. I have provided the ARM template that i am using. I think i am missing some crucial step here.

Comment: you sure you dont have a typo somewhere? that clearly points at that

Comment: i copied exactly what you have provided. I did not type anything. I will cross check again.

Comment: update: I hard code the Resource ID value in the 'identity' section, and the deployment fails with the error that it expects the 'servicePrincipalProfile'. From my experience, we can create the AKS cluster only when we provide the identity value as 'SystemAssigned'.

Comment: nah, thats not right, you are using a wrong api-version, use this one: 2020-09-01 and it will work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate. btw i tried your template and there is no issue with the variable

Comment: I used the API version 2019-08-01, because it did not allow me to use 2020-09-01. Also, I had to use the 'ServicePrincipalProfile' because i am using 'UserAssigned' in the Identity. The AKS cluster deployed now, however, when I query the Identity using the command: 'az aks show -g ITQIG-eu-rsv-manjug-dev -n ITQIG-eu-manjug-aks-dev --query "identity"', I am not able to see the managed identity in the output. {
  "principalId": null,
  "tenantId": null,
  "type": "UserAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "": {
      "clientId": null,
      "principalId": null
    }
  }
}

Comment: you have to use 2020-09-01 and you can drop the `serviceprincipalprofile`

Comment: Thank you, the deployment is working since i am hard coding the values inside the input variable. How can I pass dynamic values to it? This values for this should be dynamic: "[resourceId('58aac3e3-e3c7-41e4-8539-5fd1893c46e9', 'rg-name','Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'mi-name')]": {}

Comment: yes, like I said, the example you provided works as-is when you change the api version. if it doesnt - update your powershell\az cli to the latest